# How to embark on calibrating two cameras in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I realise there is a lot of information about calibrating cameras in a single set up and even in a stereo set up all these instances differed to me somewhat. My set up is as follows:

[image]

Within the calibration zone there will be a big chess board in which I will calibrate the camera with opencv findchessboard. The problem I have at the moment is that I have been using the calibration only for the pictures distortion, which is what I have mostly found only online. However I need to somehow find the respective positions of the cameras (x,y,z) and the angle of inclination if possible. I though surely this would be possible with some sort of calibration as to line the points up as both cameras will be looking that the same calibration configuration. Essentially my question boils down to:

1. Is there a opencv calibration which will help me with the relative distances and angles (x,y,z,θ)
2. Is it as trivial as calibrating the two cameras individually
3. If not opencv how would this be accomplished.

Comment: you could be mathematically "cheap" about it and use aruco/charuco/... -- protip: use 4x4 matrices for calculations (chaining/inverting of transformations), not rvec and tvec. write utility functions to convert between rvec/tvec and 4x4 pose matrix using cv.Rodrigues

Comment: where"s your origin in the scene? Just provide object points in absolute scene coordinates (world coordinates) to calibrateCamera function and provide precalibrated intrinsics and distortion coefficients. Or use solvePnp

Comment: @Micka in my head I had envisaged a solution which would automatically calibrate the distance and real world co-ordinates with the correct code. So that it would work on any setup. So no need to measure real life distances as they would be accounted for in the charuco

Comment: thanks @ChristophRackwitz, ill have a look into that

Comment: You have to define the scene coordinate system. If it is ok for you that the calibration pattern local origin is the origin of the scene, then you dont have to measure anything, because then object coordinates are identical to world coordinates.

Comment: print a big aruco (and measure the print), tape it on some MDF/plywood with double-sided tape (the outer edges of the marker are enough). throw it on the ground. if both cams can see it, now you have matrices to transform from marker space to each camera, and back, thus between cameras too.